# Allow user to type in only the options in mat-autocomplete in angular 6

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

I am using mat-autocomplete.

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">
        {{ option }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Was wondering if there is a way to restrict the user only to type in the options provided in the drop down ie. one,two and three only.When the user types anything else like ***sixteen*** then it shouldn't be displayed

```
 export class AutocompleteSimpleExample {
  myControl: FormControl = new FormControl();

  options = [
    'One',
    'Two',
    'Three'
   ];

}
```

Comment: That is the current behavior as far as I can tell - https://stackblitz.com/angular/yrjldemxkdb - typing anything that is not in the options does not show the drop down...

Comment: Yes, But is there any alternative for this?

Answer (score 6):

You may bind to blur event and check if the input value equals to desired input like below. I've used similar approach on my own autocomplate.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="myControl" (blur)="InputControl($event)" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
```

in component

```
InputControl(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let isValueTrue = this.options.filter(myAlias =>
            myAlias  === event.target.value);
        if (isValueTrue.length === 0) {
            this.form.get(‘MyControl’).setValue(null);
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Comment: When the user clicks the input field, types **something** in and then clicks on one of the options in the selected list, this approach becomes a race condition for two events: the blur event for when the mouse left the input field before the click on one of the options, and then the "onSelectionChange" or "optionselected" events;

I am still searching for an answer myself, wondering if perhaps Validators is the way to go.